# How Kotlin inferencing return type of function with expression body

Tags: function, kotlin, expression, type-inference

If function consists of only one expression, than its return type may be infered from that expression.
And it sounds pretty simple:

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a > b) a else b
```

In this case the return type of function will be Int.

But what type will be in the next example?

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a > b) a else true
```

Comment: it is `Any`. All you had to do was write that code into any IDE and it would show you that. If you want to know more about `Any` you [have the docs here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/)

Comment: Sorry, makes no sense.  The best answer would come from Kotlin compiler itself: try it and report back.  My guess?   "This function is incorrect."

Comment: @duffymo the function is correct and it would compile and run just fine, in Java it would be the equivalent of returning `Object`.

Comment: You have to admit that it's confusing at best.  Why would anyone write such a thing?

Comment: This particular example? No idea. But functions that return multiple types (under `Any`) are not that uncommon (not saying that they are the best solution, they usually point to a code smell).

Comment: @duffymo why does it make no sense to you? The inference just gives the closest ancestor of the types of the possible values of the expression. It makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Every max method I've ever seen, including the ones built into both Java and Kotlin, return the maximum of a and b, not a value and a boolean.  Kotlin itself disagrees with you.  The proposed function goes against the grain for every language back to C and would require repeated explanation.

Comment: @duffymo oh, right, you're talking about the goal of that max function in particular. Of course it doesn't make sense. This is just a theoretical question about the behaviour of type inference. I don't believe we should try to look at the meaning of the code here.

Comment: I see your point, Joffrey.  I don't like the example used, but the question about Any return is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inference just gives the closest ancestor of the types of the possible values of the expression.

Here your expression can yield a `Boolean` or an `Int`. The closest ancestor in this case is `Comparable<*>`, so that's the return type of your function.

If the types were completely unrelated, the common ancestor would be `Any`, which is in Kotlin the common ancestor of all non-nullable types.
If one of the values can also be null, you may end up with a return type that is `Any?`, which is the ultimate parent of all types in Kotlin (similar to Java's `Object`).